# How to export all content with feature images?

Tags: plugins, post-thumbnails, import, export

I want to export all content with featured images from my localhost WordPress site to the production blog,but when I tried using the default WordPress export-import plugins ,all content get exported (including post images) except for featured images. 
As you can see [here](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/export-posts-by-author-featured-image-reference) ,this problem is been faced by many others also .So how to export and import all content including featured images.I am using WordPress 3.4.1.